# Windows Server - PerfNet event 2004

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I´m using a SharePoint 2013 on a WS 2012 R2 Server.

Everything is ok except for one error:

**Error PefNet Event 2004**

**Message:** Unable to open the Server service performance object. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the status code.

**XML Message:**

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-PerfNet" Guid="{CAB2B8A5-49B9-4EEC-B1B0-FAC21DA05A3B}" EventSourceName="PerfNet" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49152">2004</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-09T09:21:59.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>29047</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>SPWFE1.MYDOMAIN.LOCAL</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Binary>220000C0</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

**What I've done:**

- Process Monitor (Filter: Access Denied)
- Permissions for HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Publishers{CAB2B8A5-49B9-4EEC-B1B0-FAC21DA05A3B}

But the error still occurs.

Any ideas to solve this error?

I saw this PerfNet 2004 error on different systems in my environment...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Troubleshooting Event ID 2004 Source perfnet**

As said here: https://rodolfovaraujo.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/troubleshooting-event-id-2004-source-perfnet/ it seems to be a useless event most of the time.

I’ve this System event, and decided to check.

```
Event Type:    Error
Event Source:    PerfNet
Event Category:    None
Event ID:    2004
Date:        22-04-2012
Time:        22:18:35
User:        N/A
Computer:    %computername%
Description:
Unable to open the Server service. Server performance data will not be returned. 
The error code returned is in the first DWORD in the Data section.
```

At the command prompt, type *Net Statistics* to check if services are available and if Statistics are available.

To see statistics from Server service type in command prompt *Net Statistics Server*

To see statistics from workstation service type in command prompt *Net Statistics workstation*

We can see that Server and workstation services are working as expected and no further action is needed. But if for some reason the Statistics are not available for the services, just start or restart them.

Type in command prompt *net start server*

Read more about this subject here.http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows+Operating+System&ProdVer=5.0&EvtID=2004&EvtSrc=Perfnet&LCID=1033

Hope that this information can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling the WMI Windows Management Instrumentation service. Run CMD with Administrator privileges. Or disable service when you run services.msc with administrator privileges.

```
net stop winmgmt
```

There is not much of a workaround for the problem. Even the internet does not tell much. But if you can run your system without the service? Then maybe you be able to disable it. And then to not worry about more error logs.